# How to use proper RSAPKCS1SHA256SignatureDescription with A3 Ceritificate?

Tags: c#, sha256, sign

As signing around 100 blocks of a single XML file thru a loop, I´ve got an error from server:

`"The value of the 'Algorithm' attribute does not equal its fixed value."`

So  the server is expecting:

`<SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256" />`

instead of :

`<SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1" />`

Researching I have found that the solution would be adding the rigth function:

`string signatureRSAMethod = @"http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256";`

`signer.SignedInfo.SignatureMethod = signatureRSAMethod;`

Then an exception apear:

`SignatureDescription could not be created for the signature algorithm supplied`

again the solution would be adding the line of code:

```
CryptoConfig.AddAlgorithm( typeof(RSAPKCS1SHA256SignatureDescription), signatureRSAMethod);
```

Finally the file was singed and sent ones, but, unfortunately on a second try, the private key had disappeared from my certificate, its being 3 lost so far, two were cards with readers and a Token one. Anyway, I'm suspicious something is violating some security rule that makes the private key disappear. Am I using it in a wrong way?

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out that I only need to add on the CryptoConfig ones, so I took the line below from the loop and put it on form show it solved my  problem.

> CryptoConfig.AddAlgorithm( typeof(RSAPKCS1SHA256SignatureDescription), signatureRSAMethod);